# Returning different types of ViewModel back to the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application in which at a certain point there is a page (*Index*) where a user can select an item from a DropDownList. After submitting this, the controller will return a different PartialView-name to another View (*Create*), based on the selected item from the list. Each partial has its own ViewModel and when the PartialView is sent from the Controller to *Create*-View it is rendered correctly. To achieve this I made a general ViewModel and several other viewmodels which derive from this general ViewModel. The *Create*-view has the general ViewModel as Model and the Partials, which will be rendered in the *Create*-view, have the matching derived types as Model.

But here's the problem, when I submit the form on the PartialView I have to retrieve the right ViewModel back in the Controller. Accepting the general ViewModel as a parameter won't work as I won't be able to down-cast it to the right ViewModel then.  Here's some example code that I have:

**ViewModels:**

```
public class PropertyViewModel
{
    public string ViewName { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}

public class IntegerViewModel : PropertyViewModel
{
    public int MinValue { get; set; }
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }
}

public class TextViewModel : PropertyViewModel
{
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create(String partialName)
{
    var model = GetViewModelFromName(partialName);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(???)
{
    //What to do here and what kind of parameter should I expect?
}
```

Is there a 'clean' way to do this? And does anyone know how to achieve this?

**Update:**

I have a solution that seems to work. In the PartialView I set the actionName and the controllerName of the form, like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateIntegerProperty", "Property")) {
    //Formstuff...
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateTextProperty", "Property")) {
    //Formstuff...
}
```

And in my Controller I have all the different Actions (one for each of the PartialViews). This seems to work. Now is this a clean way to do this? If anyone comes up with a better idea, please do let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your solution works then go with it.  It seems fine to me.  The only issue would arise if you were bothered about having the same URL for each action.

You could enhance it a tiny bit by adding the Action and Controller names to the base ViewModel if you wanted to, like this:

```
public class PropertyViewModel
{
    public string ViewName { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Controller { get; set; }
    public String Action { get; set; }
}
```

And then doing this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Model.Action, Model.Controller)) {
    //Formstuff...
}
```

This would be worth doing if it meant you could now use the same `View` (or partial view, or whatever) for the form.

If you DO want the same URL for each action, then one way is to override `OnModelBinding`, but I probably wouldn't bother personally.

Comment: Very good idea. I'm setting your answer as the answer of my question as everything works now as expected, and enhanced with your solution! :)

Comment: Thanks. Glad to have been of help. :-)